# Is it possible to subscribe to asset creation events in composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I realise I can emit events in chaincode and listen for those events in the node SDK.

However, I'd like to be able to receive an event when an asset is created so that I can act on that. Is this possitble?

An alternative might be the ability to specify a function which is called when an asset is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one workaround:

1. create a transaction that creates that asset with an event emitted
2. restrict the creation of an asset to one transaction only in .acl

Example:

```
rule CreateAssetOnlyWithTx{
    description: "Allow all learners to create and read their own submissions"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.example.blah.asset"
    transaction: "org.example.blah.tx"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add an asset through the transaction function, you can emit an event as soon as it is created. The event is only emitted, if the asset was successfully created FYI. See more here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html

// Add a vehicle to the asset registry and emit an event - not tested.

```
return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.Vehicle')
.then(function (vehicleAssetRegistry) {
    // Get the factory for creating new asset instances.
    var factory = getFactory();

    // Create the vehicle.

    var vehicle = factory.newResource('org.acme', 'Vehicle', 'VEHICLE_1');

    vehicle.colour = 'BLUE';

    // Add the vehicle to the vehicle asset registry.

    return vehicleAssetRegistry.add(vehicle);

})
.catch(function (error) {

// Add optional error handling here. If the transaction fails, no event is emitted please note

})
.then(function() {

     var addNotification = getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.trading', 'AddNotification');

     addNotification.vehicle = vehicle;   // the object passed into the transaction etc etc
     emit(addNotification);
})
```

Comment: Many thanks Paul. I've accepted the answer from @dtylam as that gave me a quick solution today.